# NoClassDefFoundError of using TwitterSource on Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'd like to use TwitterSource as input in a flink project. However NoClassDefFoundError occurs when I submit the job aft. I think I have already imported flink-connector-twitter package by Maven. I think it should be a problem with maven. Can anyone tells me what should I do?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What class is it complaining about not finding? Are you running in the IDE, or from the command line? If the command line, is the flink-connector-twitter jar in your classpath? Can we see the relevant parts of your pom.xml file?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/twitter/TwitterSource. I setup the project in IDE but compile with `mvn clean package` and there is no error. When I run the flink job by command line this exception occurs. I have edited and included the related part of pom.xml in the question description

Comment: It seems that a problem because of the twitter-connectors jar is not in the binary distribution of flink. If I copy the jar file into the flink lib path it will work but I really wonder how to fix the problem with maven.

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/linking.html should help (see the section on maven).

Comment: any solution for this? @Snakienn , i did like what u did, but it doesnt work , it get a new error "Cannot load user class: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.twitter.TwitterSource" , V.1.7.2